# Date format so weird, how to parse it

Tags: date, parsing

I'm faced with this date format:

```
2017-04-17T22:15:29.6645145+07:00
```

How to parse this date? I'm using swift.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer  yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ